# align the link_to with the select tag ruby on rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm using **"x"** button for closing a small form on my project. I want to align the button with the other fields just like this [image: this]  Here you can see the **x** `link_to` is aligned with the other forms. But this is what I have right now: [image: please click the image]
I'm stuck with this, I tried to manipulate the `col-` but I can't get my desired output. This is the code:

```
<div class="nested-fields" style="margin-bottom:10px;">

<div class="col-lg-8">
  <%= f.label :assembled_product_id %>
  <%= f.select :assembled_product_id,options_from_collection_for_select(AssembledProduct.all,:id, :name, :selected => f.object.assembled_product_id),{include_blank: true}, class:"select2", required: true, onchange: "setGroupPrice(this.id, this.value);" %>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :unit_price, "Unit Price" %>
    <%= f.number_field :unit_price, class: "form-control", step: 0.01, min: 0, required: true, value: "0.00", onblur: "setTwoNumberDecimal(this)" %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :discount_rate, "Discount (in %)" %>
    <%= f.number_field :discount_rate, class:" form-control", step: 0.01, min: 0, required: true, value: "0.00", onblur: "setTwoNumberDecimal(this)" %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :qty, "Qty" %>
    <div class="input-group">
      <%= f.number_field :qty, class: "form-control qty_size", min: 1, step: 1, required: true, value: "0" %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :unit %>
    <%= f.select :unit,options_from_collection_for_select(Unit.all,:name, :name, :selected => f.object.unit),{include_blank: true}, class:"select2", required: true %>
    <!-- <span class="input-group-btn" class="pull-right"> -->
      <b><%=link_to_remove_association "x", f, class:"btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs pull-right" %></b>
    <!-- </span> -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group" style="border:1px dashed darkgray; height:1px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your css look like?

Comment: `class:"btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs pull-right" ` is the issue. your input is taking 100% width. as it is `pull-right`, it means relative positioning. and hence it is on the right side, below input.